# Angular newbie: beginning to build an application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm brand new to Angular, and have read through numerous tutorials and sample apps, and now I'm doing that difficult bit where you dive into a real-world application :)

This is what I'd like to build.

- Page 1: a splash screen with a button. When the user clicks the button, they go to...
- Page 2: a welcome screen with some text.

This should be quite easy to build, right? This is what I've got so far. HTML first:

```
views/page1.html
<button ng-click="showPage2()">click me</button>

views/page2.html
<div>my splash page</div>
```

And in my JavaScript:

```
app.js
angular.module('astellasRiskfactorcalcAppApp', [
   'ngRoute'
])
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/page1.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
  .when('/page2', {
    templateUrl: 'views/page2.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  });
 }]);

controllers/main.js
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.showPage2 = function() {
    console.log('showPage2');
    // what do I do now?
  };
}]);
```

The `showSplash` module is firing OK, but what do I put in it? Should I just update the route and let Angular handle the rest? How about if I want to do a fancy CSS3 transition between one screen and the next?

Comment: For completeness, it might help if you should the html where `ng-view` exists as well.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about tutoring

Comment: The question seems pretty clear to me, I think it belongs here.

Comment: You don't even need an ng-click and a showPage2 method. A regular href on your link will do. Otherwise, you need to inject the $location service into the controller and use it to change the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in a few different ways, but the answer here is probably that you don't want a button (or at least not an ng-click, what the element looks like is irrelevant), you just want a normal "a href=''" link. As you said, let angular handle the rest.

The other way to do it would be to use the [$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location) service. It lets you change the location (url) in javascript. Unless you need to check something in your controller before you know where to send people there is no reason not to just use a normal link since the end result is the same for the user, but if you do need it it is used like this:

```
console.log($location.path());  // Gets the path
$location.path('/page2')  // Sets the path
```

As for animations, if you are using 1.1.5 or newer than you have access to [ng-animate.](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) ng-animate lets you animate most of the directives like ng-repeat, ng-show, etc. It can also animate changes in ng-view, so that you can do animated transitions between pages. Be warned that ng-animate is a bit tricky to get working, but if you find a good tutorial there is no reason not to try if you want animations.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise it was as easy as using `href`. Much appreciated.